# bulk insert into mysql (CSV file-Codeigniter)

Tags: csv

I need function or code for bulk insert categories into mysql database.I am using codeigniter for my project.

Answer (score 1):

```
START TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM `mytable`;

LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/something.csv'
INTO TABLE `mytable`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(email, login, pass)

COMMIT;
```

this can be run directly in mysql to import data from a CSV